# In table, get selected row id in array

Tags: angularjs, angular-datatables

In table every row assosiated with checkbox and have option to check all row.
I want to get selected rows id of table in array.

Here is [plunker code](https://plnkr.co/edit/ssmjCnosuzbH1SlpVvcH?p=preview).

HTML:

```
 <table id="datatable-buttons" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                                    <thead>
                                        <th>
                                              <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectRowId" ng-click="selectedAll()">
                                        </th>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody ng-init="get_product()">
                                        <!--step 6-->
                                        <tr ng-repeat="product in filtered = (pagedItems| filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:currentPage * entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit | findobj:multipleVlaue | searchFor:searchString"> <!-- searchFor:searchString --> 
                                            <td> 
                                                <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selctedIds[product.id]" ng-checked="product.deleted">
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Controller:

```
    $scope.selectedAll = function () {
    $scope.pagedItems.forEach(function (product) {
        if ($scope.selectRowId) {
            product.deleted = true;
        } else {
            product.deleted = false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: try using `$index` to get the index of the element inside ng-repeat. `$index` is actually the iterator offset of the repeated element (0..length-1)

Comment: I have tried but not getting selected ids @avantika-saini

Comment: can you please edit in plunker

Answer (score 3):

If you want something scalable that accommodates things like complex filtering, pagination, etc. then I suggest you write an *angular* property to each object.  So for the checkbox we'd want to toggle this boolean value like so:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.$selected"/>
```

For your toggle all/none, you'll need to tap a controller function:

```
$scope.toggleAll = function(bSelect){
    itemArray.forEach( function(item){ item.$selected = bSelect; })
}
```

The reason I suggest prepending your selected value with a $ like `$selected` is that any HTTP calls you make with the objects, Angular will strip any `$property` before converting to JSON, just in case your backend has issue.

I'd recommend using a filter to pull the IDs:

```
<div>{{ itemArray | getSelIds }}</div>
```

and the filter

```
.filter( 'geSeltIds', function(){
    return function(items){
        //if you happen to use lodash
        return _.chain(items).filter({$selected:true}).map('id').value()

        //manual
        ids = []
        items.forEach(function(item){
            if(item.$selected)
                ids.push(item.id)
        })
        return ids
    }
})
```

Comment: I appreciate your suggestion.  what is doing this: 
return _.chain(items).filter({$selected:true}).map('id')

Comment: If you use the lodash library, you can chain together several functions. This simply targets the items array, filters and passes an array where $selected is true and then maps the ids of the filtered items.

Comment: Rather than ignore your request, I will explain why I must respectfully decline. a) I am now starting my day at work and can't dedicate enough time to work through your example and b) I'd rather you enjoy the rewards of solving it by yourself by using the tools provided in my answer and others on this website.  You'll retain and understand much better once you've pieced it together.

Comment: Could you check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47568013/get-more-than-1000-row-in-the-data-table-in-angular-js-from-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

This filter is cleaner:

```
 .filter( function (item) {
            return item.$selected;
     }).map(function (item) { return item.id });
```